# How do you change background color on td in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change background color on table cell depending on tp1_value.
tp1_value is selected cell value from database table and it is either True or False.

How do I make this so background-color become 'green' on true, 'red' on false? Default color is grey before I click table cell which is null value.

It doesn't seem like I can use if statement on css. :(

Edit: So I came up with this but it doesn't work.. if I change if condition to (a1a = 'True'), (a1a = 'False'), it picks up green color regardless of a1a value is True or False. Help Please.

```
<td id="a1"><div class="t">
           <script>
                 var a1a = document.querySelector("#a1").value;
    
                 if (a1a === 'True') {
                       document.getElementById('a1').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
                 } else if (a1a === 'False') {
                       document.getElementById('a1').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
                 } else {
                       document.getElementById('a1').style.backgroundColor = 'black';
                 }                
           </script>
</div></td>
```

Comment: Where are you putting the value of `tp1_value` into the table?

Comment: if tp1_value is changable so you can go with
`label#true { backgorund : green; }`
`label#false { background: red; }`

Comment: Well, you would be able to use CSS if you'd combine your label with a checkbox and give the checkbox a `checked`  attribute whenever the `tp1_value` is true. But without knowing how you're rendering your HTML based on the data from your db, it's hard to say for sure that this is a viable approach. Please include some specifics on *how* you're rendering the page and the values you're rendering them with.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do that based on your server scripting language (that will talk to your db)

For example, you would create these 2 styles:

```
#tp1_green {
        background-color: green;
}
#tp1_red {
        background-color: red;
}
```

And the page would print the styles based on your server logic (ASP example below):

```
<tr>
    <td id="tp1"><div class="t">
        <label id="<%if dbvalue = "green" then%>tp1_green<%else if dbvalue = "red" then%>tp1_red<%end if%>"></label>
    </div></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using javascript to apply conditional logic:

```
var tp1Cell = document.getElementById("tp1")
var tp1Value = document.getElementById("tp1_value").html

If (tp1Value === "True") {
    tp1Cell.style.backgroundColor = 'green'
} else {
    tp1Cell.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
}
```

Comment: Since OP didn't share how he renders the html based on his database values, it is pretty useless to state that he needs javascript. You cannot know for sure that this is the best solution.

Comment: I certainly do not claim that I have ever provided or will provide on any subject is the best anwer. I, like many other on this site, have merely provided an answer. I have edited my answer to no longer include the definitive article "needs".

Comment: if condition isn't working for me. :(  i edited my question.

Comment: Hit f12 and put a break on the if statement line. Check the value of a1a. Maybe your data is coming in as always True?

Answer (score 0):

let's say that tp1_value is changeable with any condition, so you have to set your code as per the result,

here is a snippet shows the result in case the id is changeable between true and false.

```js
document.querySelector('.ftrue').addEventListener('click', function() {
document.querySelector('label').setAttribute('id', "true");
});
document.querySelector('.ffalse').addEventListener('click', function() {
document.querySelector('label').setAttribute('id', "false");
});
```

```css
label#true {
background: green;
color:white;
}
label#false {
background: red;
color:white;
}
```

```html
<table class="t1">

            <tr>
                <td id="tp1"><div class="t"><label id="tp1_value">[Text]</label></div></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
    
    <button class="ftrue">True</button>
    <button class="ffalse">false</button>
```